# Trigger another instance's function from within a different instance of same object

Tags: javascript, timer

I'm a bit of a beginner with Javascript and am struggling to figure out how to use a function of one instance to trigger a function in another instance, and vice versa, both of the same class. Let me explain what I mean.

My project is to build a Pomodoro Clock in Javascript. Pomodoro is a process where you work for a specified time (25 minutes, for example), then take a short break (5 mins), and then repeat. The clocks should run back to back, indefinitely or until the user stops it.

I need the completion of one clock to trigger the beginning of the other one, and vice versa.

I built a working program using completely separate, slightly varying functions for each timer (with much redundancy). I tried to simplify my code by creating a class of Timers and building each one from that. That's where I've got stuck.

I have a function in my Timer class which, when the timer reaches zero, needs to call the other timer's countdown to begin (line 126 on Codepen). How can I do that?

Thank you for any help you can offer.

Here's my project on Codepen: https://codepen.io/lieberscott/pen/baRpgx?editors=1010

And my Javascript code below:

```
let session; // session Timer object instance
let btimer; // break Timer object instance

let s_off; // boolean for whether session timer is off or on
let s_timer; // reference to session timer HTML element
let s_stop; // reference to session stop HTML button
let s_increase; // reference to session increase HTML button
let s_decrease; // reference to session decrease HTML button

// same variables as above for break timer
let b_off;
let b_timer;
let b_stop;
let b_increase;
let b_decrease;


$(document).ready(function() {
  s_off = true;
  s_timer = $("#timer");
  s_stop = $("#stop");
  s_increase = $("#increase");
  s_decrease = $("#decrease");
  b_off = true;
  b_timer = $("#breaktimer");
  b_stop = $("#breakstop");
  b_increase = $("#breakincrease");
  b_decrease = $("#breakdecrease");

  session = new Timer(1, 60, s_off, s_timer, s_stop, s_increase, s_decrease);
  btimer = new Timer(5, 60, b_off, b_timer, b_stop, b_increase, b_decrease);

  // increase session minutes
  $(s_increase).on("click", function() {
    if (session.off) {
      session.min++;
      session.sec = 00;
      s_timer.html(session.min + ":" + session.sec);
    }
  });

  // decrease session minutes
  $(s_decrease).on("click", function() {
    if (session.off) {
      if (session.min > 1) {
        session.min--;
      }
      session.sec = 00;
      s_timer.html(session.min + ":" + session.sec);
    }
  });

  // increase break minutes
  $(b_increase).on("click", function() {
    if (btimer.off) {
      btimer.min++;
      btimer.sec = 00;
      b_timer.html(btimer.min + ":" + btimer.sec);
    }
  });

  // decrease break minutes
  $(b_decrease).on("click", function() {
    if (btimer.off) {
      if (btimer.min > 1) {
        btimer.min--;
      }
      btimer.sec = 00;
      b_timer.html(btimer.min + ":" + btimer.sec);
    }
  });

  // begin session timer by clicking on the timer itself
  $(s_timer).on("click", function() {
    session.time();
  });

  // stop session timer
  $(s_stop).on("click", function() {
    session.off = true;
    session.stopClock(session.intervalFunction);
  });

  // stop break timer
  $(b_stop).on("click", function() {
    btimer.off = true;
    btimer.stopClock(btimer.intervalFunction);
  });

});


class Timer {
  constructor(min, sec, off, disp, stopButton, increaseButton, decreaseButton) {
    this.min = min; // minutes
    this.minsSet = min; // minutes again, this will be used to reset the timer
    this.sec = sec;
    this.off = off; // boolean saying whether timer is off or not
    this.disp = disp; // HTML display
    this.stopButton = stopButton;
    this.increaseButton = increaseButton;
    this.decreaseButton = decreaseButton;
    this.func;
  }

  time() { // function fired when the timer is clicked
    if (this.off) {
      this.off = false;
      this.func = this.intervalFunc();
    }
  }

  intervalFunc() { // set the interval of the timer
    setInterval(function() {this.countdown();}, 1000); // ERROR HERE
  }

  countdown() { // interval to complete for duration of timer
    // check if clock reaches zero
    if (this.sec == 0) {
      this.min--;
      this.sec = 60;
      if (this.min < 0) {
        this.min = this.minsSet;
        this.sec = 0;
        this.off = true;
        this.time(); // this needs to trigger, not this.time(), but the OTHER object's time() function
        this.stopClock(this.func); // clearInterval() function below
      }
    }

    // if clock is not at 0:00, display new time
    this.sec--;
    let m = this.min.toString();
    let s;
    if (this.sec < 10) {
      s = "0" + this.sec.toString()
    }
    else {
      s = this.sec.toString();
    }
    this.disp.html(m + ":" + s);
  }

  stopClock() {
    clearInterval(this.func);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Edited with just one question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) I tried your code and fixed some bugs, your setInterval issue is because "this" points to window object there.

2) for calling the other object time() method, first off you need something to know which object you are working with, so I have added a type variable to the class and then in the countdown function i have added a check.
Changes are in this pen :

https://codepen.io/yaduvanshi/pen/dJRdeR?editors=0010

```
intervalFunc() { // set the interval of the timer
   var that =this;
   setInterval(function() {that.countdown();}, 1000); // ERROR HERE
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps. Still some bugginess with the buttons upon the operation of the timers. Playing around with it now before I check off this answer.

Comment: Bugginess was my own. Clock is working as I wanted now. Codepen link for those interested, with comments at top: https://codepen.io/lieberscott/pen/zpzWOo

Comment: Final final version for those interested: https://codepen.io/lieberscott/full/KZqOBQ/

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution that you are looking for, is the .bind() or the .call() that Javascript provides you with (Function.prototype.bind()). For example, the .bind() function takes the specific object instance as argument. You can read up on the same here
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind